# pandas/python: search loops between 2 df and input end result to new df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

is it possible to create a "search" loop (within a range, example: iloc 0 to 10, 0 to 21, etc ..) using two different df(s) and input the end result into a new df.

below is the manual method i uses. however, it is very inefficient.

```
ndf0 = df[(df['result'] == rc.iloc[0]['result'])].drop_duplicates(['result'], keep='last')
ndf1 = df[(df['result'] == rc.iloc[1]['result'])].drop_duplicates(['result'], keep='last')
ndf2 = df[(df['result'] == rc.iloc[2]['result'])].drop_duplicates(['result'], keep='last')
ndf3 = df[(df['result'] == rc.iloc[3]['result'])].drop_duplicates(['result'], keep='last')
ndf4 = df[(df['result'] == rc.iloc[4]['result'])].drop_duplicates(['result'], keep='last')
ndf5 = df[(df['result'] == rc.iloc[5]['result'])].drop_duplicates(['result'], keep='last')
ndf6 = df[(df['result'] == rc.iloc[6]['result'])].drop_duplicates(['result'], keep='last')
ndf7 = df[(df['result'] == rc.iloc[7]['result'])].drop_duplicates(['result'], keep='last')
ndf8 = df[(df['result'] == rc.iloc[8]['result'])].drop_duplicates(['result'], keep='last')
..etc...

frames = [ndf0, ndf1, ndf2, ndf3, ndf4, ndf5, ndf6, ndf7, ndf8, etc..]
result = pd.concat(frames)
```

Many thanks, regards

example tables:

df

```
╔════════╦════════╗
║ result ║ rating ║
╠════════╬════════╣
║ purple ║     11 ║
║ blue   ║     33 ║
║ yellow ║     54 ║
║ green  ║     55 ║
║ red    ║     64 ║
║ brown  ║     37 ║
║ white  ║     95 ║
║ glod   ║     99 ║
║ tan    ║     47 ║
║ black  ║     67 ║
╚════════╩════════╝
```

rc

```
╔════════╗
║ result ║
╠════════╣
║ blue   ║
║ yellow ║
║ red    ║
║ tan    ║
║ white  ║
╚════════╝
```

ndf

```
╔════════╦════════╗
║ result ║ rating ║
╠════════╬════════╣
║ blue   ║     33 ║
║ yellow ║     54 ║
║ red    ║     64 ║
║ tan    ║     47 ║
║ white  ║     95 ║
╚════════╩════════╝
```

Comment: What does `rc` look like? Can you update your post with the output of `df['result'].head(10)` and `rc['result'].head(5)` to create a reproducible example, please?

Comment: hi @ Corralien, i've updated my post with the tables, hope, it will give better picture of the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
>>> rc.merge(df, on='result', how='left').drop_duplicates('result', keep='last')

   result  rating
0    blue      33
1  yellow      54
2     red      64
3     tan      47
4   white      95
```

*Note: in your sample, you have no duplicates.*

Comment: this works perfectly, however, the duplicates weren't dropped and i have to add anothe line:  df1 = df1.drop_duplicates(['result'], keep='last')

Comment: i only used a short sample, the original df has plently of duplicates

Comment: I fixed my answer. I had forgotten `'results'` in `drop_duplicates`. It's not necessary to use the sequence syntax `['results']` if you have only one column to check.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want to select a part of data from `df` on condition that the values of `df['result']` are included by `rc['result']`.

If so, maybe you can use mask to select them and then drop the duplicates keeping the last row.

Try this:

```
mask = (df['result'].isin(rc['result'].to_list()))
new_df = df[mask].drop_duplicates(['result'], keep='last')
```

Hope it will give you some help.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. is it possible to have the output uses the sequence from the rc['result']?

Comment: I replaced the keyword `keeping` by `keep`.

Comment: Thank you. I did not notice that mistake.  : )

Answer (score 0):

hmm.... wouldn't this just work directly?

```
df = df[[rc.columns.tolist()]]
```

Comment: What is it supposed to do?